# Ancestry showing wrong connection?

Tags: ancestry.com, family-tree

Ancestry is showing that I am my grandfather.  When I click on my name, it shows that I am my granddaughter.

Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: First check to be sure that you are are the Home person and that you are the identified as "Who you are in this tree".  This is found under "settings" for your tree.

Comment: @BobE Kim already is the Home person and "who you are in this tree" -- if that were not the case, the relationship calculator wouldn't appear.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the Edit Relationships option to remove any incorrect relationships.  It is found at top right of the Person page under the Edit pulldown.

[image]

---

[image]